# Can I change the type of elements in the Microdata format?

Tags: html, html5, microdata

With regard to Microdata I was wondering if the elements must be exactly like the examples (http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176035) or that Google/Bing look if the `itemprop` attributes occur on certain elements.

For example, could I replace this:

```html
<div itemprop="name">some text</div>
```

with this:

```html
<span itemprop="name">some text</span>
```

without affecting its functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of tag can be either div or span without changing how micro-data is extracted.  Here is a site giving examples with itemprop on a span tag: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html

The best way to know for sure that Google will accept your markup, is to test it with the [Google Structured Data Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you [may use any HTML5 element](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/63180/17633) for Microdata.

Bute note that [some elements come with special rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871012/1591669):

- elements with `href`/`src` attribute (e.g., `a`, `link`, `img`, etc.) create a **URI** as value
- the `time` element creates a **datetime** as value

All other elements create a **string** as value. This is usually the element’s content, but in some cases it’s the value of an attribute:

- for `meta` elements: the value of the `content` attribute
- for `data` and `meter` elements: the value of the `value` attribute