# Schema.org SiteNavigationElement markup

Tags: html5, microdata, schema.org

Should the Schema.org `SiteNavigationElement` be structured like this

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    <ul>
        <li itemprop="url"><a href="#" itemprop="name">Link 1</a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

or like this?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Link 1</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: see > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491102/what-is-the-correct-use-of-schema-org-sitenavigationelement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your questions seem to be:

- Can I specify `itemprop="url"` on `li`?
- Can I specify `itemprop="name"` on `a`?

The answer to both of these questions is: No, you should not do that. [Microdata defines special parsing rules for elements like `a`.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/63189/17633)

Schema.org’s [`url` property](http://schema.org/url) expects a URL as value. Microdata defines that you have to use elements like `a`/`area`/`link`/etc. ([essentially](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/82198/17633) any element with a `src` or `href` attribute) for specifying URLs. In your first example, the value for the `url` property would *not* be the URL, but the text "Link 1".

Because properties on `a` elements (if they have a `href` attribute) always take the `href` content (and not the element content) as value, your first example would have the URL as value for the [`name` property](http://schema.org/name) (but it expects Text, not URL, of course).

So: Your first example would produce wrong results. Your second example is fine.

Note that it would also be possible to omit the `span` element. Instead of

```html
<li>
  <a href="#" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Link 1</span></a>
</li>
```

you could use

```html
<li itemprop="name">
  <a href="#" itemprop="url">Link 1</a>
</li>
```

(See also [my similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22284473/1591669) to a question on Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Search Engine Land](http://searchengineland.com/schema-markup-structured-data-seo-opportunities-site-type-231077), it's supposed to look like this:

```
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    <li itemprop="name">
        <a itemprop="url" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="name">
        <a itemprop="url" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="name">
        <a itemprop="url" href="#">Travel Resources</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

SiteNavigationElement has a problem for me, and for some other people as well, like we can see in the question posted by @bybe in a comment. we can say that the problem is lack of scope.

Is SiteNavigationElement referred to a single item of the navigation system, and so it is read as: **an Element of the Navigation of the Site**. Or it is referred to the whole navigation system, and so it is read as: **The Navigation Element of the Site**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPageElement">
            <link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://schema.org/ItemList" />
            <meta itemprop="name" content="navigation_menu" />
            <ul>
                <li itemprop="additionalType" itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
                    <span itemprop="itemListElement">
                        <a href="http://www.example.com/link_1" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Link 1</span></a>
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li itemprop="additionalType" itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
                    <span itemprop="itemListElement">
                        <a href="http://www.example.com/link_2" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Link 2</span></a>
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which is a bit more complex, since not just considers each member of the navigation system as an element who deserves a tag, it also requires a combined syntax, using *additionalType* to convey the idea that those links are a list of items that belong to something.

**Update**

I have changed the codes on this answer to the above version, to adapt it to a way that works and validates as microdata and HTML. In the edition history of the question you can see the options I used early. I replaced those codes because

- I had an error on the first part, using a property where a type should be. Although Structured Data Testing Tool validated it with no errors
- The HTML option, validated fine but as I mentioned, the way to achieve that breaks the microdata parsing method only reading the last Item.
- As of the time of this message, doesn't seem to be a way to have two types on a single itemtype. That can be checked on the W3C [WebSchemas/additionalTypeProposal](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/additionalTypeProposal), although that hasn't been updated since May 2013.

Comment: (1) Note that [Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.de/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) is *not* a validator, it doesn’t *necessarily* show wrong HTML/Microdata/Schema.org usage. -- (2) [It *is* specified that you must use these specific elements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19728910/1591669) when having a URL as value.