# Arrange parent and child order in schema.org Microdata

Tags: html, microdata

According to 'http://schema.org/docs/full.html'

`Article`, `WebPage`, `WebPageElement` are in the same level.

`WPSideBar` is child of `WebPageElement`.

Now, should I add child under parent or is this code is correct?

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar">

    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    </div>

    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    </div>

    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    </div>

<div>
```

Comment: "Should I add child under parent": Could you give an example how that would look like?

Comment: at current example...WPSideBar is child of WebPageElement ...right?WebPageElement and Article are in same level...Now is it possible child of WebPageElement be parent of Article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine.

The hierarchy doesn’t matter in that sense (it has other purposes). You can use whichever types you want (you should respect [Schema.org’s expected types](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#schemaorg_expected), though).

A simple example: A [`MedicalScholarlyArticle`](http://schema.org/MedicalScholarlyArticle) (which is a type pretty deep in the hierarchy: `Thing > CreativeWork > Article > ScholarlyArticle > MedicalScholarlyArticle`) can reference (i.e., include as child) a [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing) (which is the super type of *everything*):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MedicalScholarlyArticle">
  <span itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">The whole universe.</span>
</div>
```

---

However, note that in your specific example, the "children" items are *not* related to the parent item. They only happen to be nested under this item, but there is no property that connects them. So Microdata parsers won’t recognize that there is a parent/children relation, it’s "flat" for them:

```
WPSideBar
Article
Article
Article
```

If you’d use a property (for example [`about`](http://schema.org/about)), parsers would recognize the relationship:

```
WPSideBar
    about Article
    about Article
    about Article
```

Comment: I think that having about Article underneath/nested on a WPSideBar would be incorrect since that implies that the sidebar is about each article's subject, which is not the case. It's true that the relation between elements that are not direct descendants of each other may be or seem "flat" or unlinked. I'd link them using additionalType and ItemList, but then you have the problem of non valid HTML (at least I don't know a way to use it and have valid HTML). What's your perspective on this?

Comment: Thank you @unor, your last Note you said me is better to use a property...In my structure I use 'text',But You use 'about'...which one is better?

Comment: @PatomaS: I don’t feel strongly about using the [`about`](http://schema.org/about) property here (though, next to [`mentions`](http://schema.org/mentions) and [`citation`](http://schema.org/citation), it’s the only property that allows referencing a `Article`). --- What do you think would be appropriate as content for `about` in a `WPSideBar` then?

Comment: @PatomaS: Regarding `additionalType` and `ItemList`: I’m not sure I understand what you mean (maybe this would make a good separate question?). I’d say you would get invalid Microdata by using properties from `ItemList` that way.

Comment: @user2726957: The [`text` property](http://schema.org/text) seems to be a better choice than `about`, yes, **but** it expects *Text* as value, not a different item (`Article` in your case). You’d have to decide if or if not you want to "break" with [Schema.org’s recommendation re. expected types](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#schemaorg_expected) here.

Comment: @unor. I mean that the syntax you used is not right since neither the sidebar is about articles, nor the articles are about the sidebar. About getting invalid microdata, you can check the code I posted here ( https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58926/schema-sitenavigationelement-markup/58935#58935 ) You'll see that is valid microdata, the problem is validating the HTML, which doesn't allow spaces on atributes, and %20 also doesn't work. So the only way to be semantically correct with the original question here, is to have separate items on the sidebar or invalid HTML

Comment: @PatomaS: It depends on the definition of "subject matter" if it’s appropriate to use `about` or not. I’m not a native English speaker, so I’m not so sure about it, but then I wonder: What *would* be the subject matter of the sidebar? --  Which spaces do you mean? It’s totally fine to have several space-separated values for `itemtype` (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21969655/1591669)) resp. `itemprop` (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14216506/1591669)).

Answer (score 1):

You can add parent elements, from the tree perspective inside child elements.

So, for instance your example is valid, of course it need some more items, but it would be OK. I did a little test with the next code and it's recognised properly

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="lateral_section" />
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
        <p itemprop="name">title of article</p>
        by <p itemprop="author">author name</p>
    </div>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
        <p itemprop="name">title of article</p>
        by <p itemprop="author">author name</p>
    </div>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
        <p itemprop="name">title of article</p>
        by <p itemprop="author">author name</p>
    </div>
<div>
```