# Are Microdata attributes valid on any element?

Tags: html5, microdata

Is it valid to add Microdata attributes (e.g., using the Schema.org vocabulary), such as `itemprop="name"`, to HTML elements that aren’t `span` or `div`?

For example:

```html
<h2 class="product_name" itemprop="name">Baseball Glove</h2>
```

Comment: I do not know, but you can test this with Google Rich Snippet Tools. (I am sure you already know that.) Just create a smaller/simpler test case as not to complicate things too much and see what you get.

Comment: Very thorough answer from unor below, but I guess your question is prompted by the fact that Google, Schema.org etc. show examples with noting but `<span>`s and `<div>`s - I think they do that to simplify their examples by sidestepping questions of semantic structure and so on that are beside the point for their purposes, it's not an indication that microdata _has_ to be used in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, you can use *every* HTML5 element for Microdata …

Microdata defines 5 new attributes for HTML5:

- `itemid`
- `itemprop`
- `itemref`
- `itemscope`
- `itemtype`

Let’s see where they can be used. [Section 5.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#items) says:

> Every HTML element may have an `itemscope` attribute specified.

So *every* element can have `itemscope`. Further on it says:

> Elements with an `itemscope` attribute may have an `itemtype` attribute specified

So if it has `itemscope` (and we learned that every element can have it), it can have `itemtype`, too. Next:

> Elements with an `itemscope` attribute and an `itemtype` attribute […] may also have an `itemid` attribute specified

If it has `itemscope` and `itemtype`, it can have `itemid`, too. And:

> Elements with an `itemscope` attribute may have an `itemref` attribute specified

If it has `itemscope`, it can have `itemref`.

Only `itemprop` is missing now. It’s defined in [Section 5.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#names:-the-itemprop-attribute):

> Every HTML element may have an `itemprop` attribute specified

So `itemprop` can also be used on every element.

(Note that Microdata (W3C Note) [refers to the HTML5 spec for defining what a "HTML element" is](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#terminology), so essentially "HTML element" means "HTML5 element".)

### … but some elements get a different content model (when `itemprop` is used)

See [8.1 Content models](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#content-models).

For example:

- `href` becomes a required attribute for `a` and `area`
- `data` becomes a required attribute for `iframe`
- the attributes `name`, `http-equiv` and `charset` are no longer allowed on `meta`
- …

### … and some elements have special rules for determining the property value (when `itemprop` is used)

→ See [5.4 Values](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#values).

For example:

- [Special rules for links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20283706/1591669). Here `foobar`’s value is the URL `http://example.com/`, not the string `Link`:

  ```html
  <a href="http://example.com/" itemprop="foobar">Link</a>
  ```
- Here `foobar`’s value is `5`, not `10`:

  ```html
  <data value="5" itemprop="foobar">10</data>
  ```
- …

---

(Taken from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20889900/1591669) to a closed question on SO.)

Comment: Awesome, detailed, and complete answer. Thanks, unor!